# Compute the norm of $T:\ell^{2}\longrightarrow \ell^{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I have an operator $T$ on $\ell^{2}$ defined by $T(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n},...)=(0,0,3x_{1},2x_{2},4x_{3},3x_{4},2x_{5},4x_{6},...)$. I have showed that this operator is continuous by choosing the constant $M=4$ to set the inequality $\|T(x)\|\leq M\|x\|$. Now I need to find the norm of $T$, that is to say I need to find the infimun of the $M$'s that satifies the inequality $\|T(x)\|\leq M\|x\|$. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It's not apparent what the pattern of coefficients is in this example, but that operator has norm at least $5$.

Comment: Sorry, there is one mistake.

Comment: Have you try $x_{3k} = 2^{-k}$ and zero otherwise? Of course you use $M=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S(x_n)=(a_nx_n)$ where $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence. The $ \|S\|=\sup_n |a_n|$. To see this first note that $\|S\| \leq \sup_n |a_n|$ is immediate from defintion. If $(e_n)$ is the standard orthonormal  basis for $\ell^{2}$ the $Se_n=a_ne_n$ and this gives $\|S\| \geq |a_n|$ for all $n$. Hence $\|S\| \geq \sup_n |a_n|$. In our case the norm of $T$ is $4$ because the norm of $T$ is same as the norm of the operator that send $(x_n)$ to $(3x_1,2x_2,4x_3,3x_4,2x_5,4x_6,....)$. .

Comment: I am assuming that the coefficients $3,2,4$ get repeated in the definition of $T$.